# Does incomplete differentials $\delta Q$ or $\delta W$ have potentials?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, entropy, differentiation, mathematics

I am very confused because my text book have following formula.

> $$dU = \delta Q  \tag  {1-1}$$
>   $$dU = \delta W  \tag  {1-1'}$$

Because these might mathematically mean "incomplete derivative = complete derivative."
(See the column named **【Summary of the description of my text book】** below.)

> **【My questions】**
>
> - How should we mathematically justify the formula $dU = \delta Q$ or　$dU = \delta W$ ?
> - Does incomplete differentials $\delta Q$ or $\delta W$ have potentials if they are [restricted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) on some sub manifold in the State space ?

Here,

- $\delta Q $ and $\delta W $ be differential 1-forms representing heat and work that Inflow/Outflow during the micro process, respectively and
- $T$, $U$ and $S$ be a scalar-valued function representing temperature, internal energy, and entropy, respectively.
- We ignore the chemical potential. **(We suppose $dN=0$)**

**【Comments】**

**■ Comment on $dU = \delta Q$:** 
I know that, from the physical viewpoint, that (1-1) means $\delta W = 0$. In other words, there are no work from outside. That is results of comparison with the first law of thermodynamics.

Perhaps the $dU = \delta Q$ makes sense mathematically only on the sub-manifold that satisfies "$dT \wedge dS=0$", am I right? (See (1-3) below).

In general, the following holds:
$$\delta Q = TdS \tag  {1-2}$$

According to the [calculation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_axioms) of the exterior derivative of the "product of scalar-valued function and a one-form", and "dd=0",

$$d(TdS) = dT \wedge dS + TddS = dT \wedge dS \tag  {1-3}$$

From (1-2), (1-3), The following shall be hold:

$$d(\delta Q) = 0 \ \ iff \ \ dT \wedge dS=0 \tag  {1-4}$$

According to the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Areas_in_the_plane), it might be $ dT \wedge dS =0$ iff

- $dT =0$ or
- $dS =0$ or
- $dT$ and $dS$ is linearly independent.

**■ Comment on $dU = \delta W$:** 
Similarly, I know that, the physical viewpoint, that means $\delta Q = 0$. In other words, there are no heat from outside. That is results of comparison with the first law of thermodynamics.

Perhaps it makes sense mathematically only on the submanifold that satisfies "$dP \wedge dV =0$ ", am I right? (See (1-3)' below)

Similarly, ignoring the effects of chemical potential the following holds:
$$\delta W = -PdV \tag  {1-2'}$$

According to the calculation rule of the exterior derivative of the "product of scalar-valued function and a one-form", and dd=0,

$$d(PdV) =-( dP \wedge dV + PddV) = - dP \wedge dV \tag  {1-3'}$$

From (1-2)', (1-3)', The following shall be hold:

$$d(\delta Q) = 0 \ \ iff \ \ dP \wedge dV=0 \tag  {1-4'}$$

According to the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Areas_in_the_plane), it might be $dP \wedge dV =0$  iff

- $dP =0$ or
- $dS =0$ or
- $dP$ and $dV$ is linearly independent.

> **【Summary of the description of my text book】**
>
> According to the first law of thermodynamics, 
>   $$dU = \delta Q +  \delta W\tag  {2-1}$$
>
> **■$dU = \delta Q$ is satisfied during isovolumic 
>   Quasi-static changes:** 
>   Consider the isovolumic Quasi-static changes.
>   The $dV$ must always be 0 during the process, therefore,
>
> $$\delta W = pdV = 0 \tag  {2-2}$$
>
> From (2-1) and (2-2), we obtain (1-1).
>   $$dU = \delta Q \tag  {1-1}$$
>
> **■ $dU = \delta W$ is satisfied during Quasi-static adiabatic change**: 
>   Consider the adiabatic change.
>   Therefore, during the process, therefore,
>    $$\delta Q  = 0 \tag  {2-2'}$$
>
> From (2-1) and (2-2'), 
>   $$dU = \delta Q \tag  {1-1'}$$

Comment: Qmechanic, Aaron Stevens: Thank you for your editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer only for the first part (equation 1-1). The other is analogical.

The submanifold is given by $\delta W=0=>dV=0$.

Moreover you don't want $d(TdS)=0$, you want $TdS=df$, where $f=f(S,V)$ is some function of coordinates $S$ and $V$. In this case, the integral will be path independent:
$$\int_\gamma\delta Q=\int_\gamma df=f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))=f(B)-f(A),$$
where $\gamma$ is the curve along which you integrate from point A to point B.

As to your $dT\land dS$, you get:
$$dT(V,S)\land dS=\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}dV\land dS,$$ so the appropriate submanifold indeed satisfies this condition, but the condition is not sufficient. And it is not so surprising that the conidtion is satisfied. In 2 dimensional space the 2-form can always be written in the form $g(x,y)dx\land dy$ no matter the coordinates or the 2 form, so the condition is satisfied for any one dimensional submanifold defined by constancy of some coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But according to the Stokes's theorem, what happens if we make a loop using another path γ'? Is the manifold defined by dV = 0 one-dimensional? So, isn't it affected by Stokes' theorem? (Because the area surrounded by the loop is always 0?)

Comment: @BlueVarious Yes, the submanifold is one dimensional. Therefore, there is only one path between any two points and making a loop simply means traversing the same path back, so indeed the area is 0. There is no other option in one dimensional case. Moreover TdS being total derivative is trivial, because there is only one coordinate (S) on which T can depend so T(S)dS=df(S) is automatically satisfied, that is every one form in one dimensional space is exact.

Comment: I understand.　Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

A clearer approach exists to address the first two questions in each part. The full expression for internal energy change is as below.

$$ dU = \delta q + \delta w$$

The total internal energy change of a system is independent of path. Internal energy is a state property, and the above is a state function.

In systems with no heat flow, the process that occurs is adiabatic. We write

$$ dU_{ad} = \delta w$$

In rigid systems with no other work, we write

$$ dU_{\delta w = 0} = \delta q $$

In summary, we start from the full first law and apply the assumptions to obtain the special forms. The questions you have seem to suggest that you are trying to prove the assumptions from the special forms, which is a reversal of the proper approach.

Both heat (flow) and work (flow) are path dependent. Perhaps in the language that you need, we can traverse a range of paths on the manifold to obtain a range of paths on the $(T, p, V)$ manifold that defines a process space. Each has its own unique values of $\delta q$ and $\delta w$. One path is adiabatic. One path has no work of any type. All other paths have unique combinations of $\delta q$ and $\delta w$. As long as we start and end at the same $(T, p, V)$ points on the manifold, the $dU$ will be the same regardless of the path.

In the same way, the statements that $\delta q = T_{sys} dS$ and $\delta w = -p_{sys} dV$ apply *after* assumptions are made (they are not to be used to "reverse engineer" a proof). The primary assumption that is required for both of these is that the process under consideration is reversible. In this case, the system and the surroundings are in exact thermal, mechanical, and chemical equilibrium at all times. The next assumption is that the system only undergoes mechanical work; no "other" work happens.

With these two assumptions, we define a specific set of paths on the manifold -- those that are reversible and have only mechanical work. Along these paths, we can write the first law identically as

$$ dU_{sys} = T_{sys} dS_{sys} - p_{sys} dV_{sys}$$

Finally, any closed system has a mechanical equation of state for $(T, V, p)$. Only two of these parameters are independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood.